# My country (iraq) is not among the payment options when trying to purchase a Firebase plan

Tags: firebase

[image]

My country is not among the payment options when trying to purchase a Firebase plan

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency "If your country or region is not listed here, this might indicate that your country or region's currency is not supported for Google Cloud charges. In these instances, your Cloud Billing account might incur charges in USD."

Comment: you should talk to google cloud support https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Comment: Iraq might be subject to [EAR](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/regulations/export-administration-regulations-ear) ...which means you need another provider.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question that should be addressed to Firebase Customer Service. This site is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool. We cannot assist with support for off-site service or vendor accounts or policies.